# Converting string list into integer list beginning from 1

Tags: python, string, integer

I want to know a method to convert a list of strings such as:
myList = ["Bob1", "Bob2", "Bob3", "Bob4"]

Somehow into integers so that they are 0, 1, 2, 3
**And then so that they are 1, 2, 3, 4** and then once I've done my calculations, I need to return the answers to the correct string in myList.

The reason for wanting to do this is because I want to use these in nth term and to do that I need to do some arithmetic so I need to be able to use number/int values to be able to calculate them and then I can return them as *string* values once the arithmetic is complete, based on the final number/int result.

EDIT: Solved this.

Comment: don't see any difference between your questions

Comment: You can just add clarification to [the last time you asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021335/changing-lists-from-string-to-int-and-vice-versa)...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the OP repeating his same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> myList = ["Bob1", "Bob2", "Bob3", "Bob4"]
>>> range(1, len(myList) + 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this. 
I did my nth term problem and had to remove each string one by one until I had one value left and returned that. I needed to count from 1-4 rather than 0-3, do the calculations then return the answer in string format.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, you may want to use enumerate and operate on the integer in the tuples:

```
myList = ["Bob1", "Bob2", "Bob3", "Bob4"]

li=[(i,s) for i,s in enumerate(myList,1)]

print li
# [(1, 'Bob1'), (2, 'Bob2'), (3, 'Bob3'), (4, 'Bob4')]
```

Then you can operate on the int part of the tuple:

```
print [t[1] for t in li if not t[0]%2]
# ['Bob2', 'Bob4']
print sum(t[0] for t in li if not t[0]%2)
# 6
```

Then just peel the number off when you are done:

```
print [s for i,s in li]
# ['Bob1', 'Bob2', 'Bob3', 'Bob4']
```